# How can I add the "system" message into my prompt?

Tags: flutter, chatgpt-api, flutterflow

I've been trying to integrate `gpt-3.5-turbo` in my `Flutter` app while maintaining the chat history. I used `FlutterFlow` to generate the boilerplate code and then downloaded the code to further edit it. I have successfully integrated the model while maintaining the chat history but I am unable to figure out how to add the `"system"` message into the `prompt`.

Here's the API call code:

```
class OpenAIChatGPTGroup {
  static String baseUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1';
  static Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  static SendFullPromptCall sendFullPromptCall = SendFullPromptCall();
}

class SendFullPromptCall {
  Future<ApiCallResponse> call({
    String? apiKey = 'sk-xxxxxxxxxx',
    dynamic? promptJson,
  }) {
    final prompt = _serializeJson(promptJson);
    final body = '''
{
  "messages": ${prompt},
  "temperature": 0.8,
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo"
}''';
    return ApiManager.instance.makeApiCall(
      callName: 'Send Full Prompt',
      apiUrl: '${OpenAIChatGPTGroup.baseUrl}/chat/completions',
      callType: ApiCallType.POST,
      headers: {
        ...OpenAIChatGPTGroup.headers,
        'Authorization':
            'Bearer sk-xxxxxxxxxx',
      },
      params: {},
      body: body,
      bodyType: BodyType.JSON,
      returnBody: true,
      encodeBodyUtf8: true,
      decodeUtf8: true,
      cache: false,
    );
  }

  dynamic createdTimestamp(dynamic response) => getJsonField(
        response,
        r'''$.created''',
      );
  dynamic role(dynamic response) => getJsonField(
        response,
        r'''$.choices[:].message.role''',
      );
  dynamic content(dynamic response) => getJsonField(
        response,
        r'''$.choices[:].message.content''',
      );
}
```

Here's `_serializeJson()` function:

```
String _serializeJson(dynamic jsonVar, [bool isList = false]) {
  jsonVar ??= (isList ? [] : {});
  try {
    return json.encode(jsonVar);
  } catch (_) {
    return isList ? '[]' : '{}';
  }
}
```

Here's the code in the `onPressed()` function of the submit button:

```
setState(() {
                                    _model.chatHistory =
                                        functions.saveChatHistory(
                                            _model.chatHistory,
                                            functions.convertToJSON(
                                                _model.textController.text));
                                  });
                                  _model.chatGPTResponse =
                                      await OpenAIChatGPTGroup
                                          .sendFullPromptCall
                                          .call(
                                    apiKey:
                                        'sk-xxxxxxxxxx',
                                    promptJson: _model.chatHistory,
                                  );
```

Here's `saveChatHistory()` function:

```
dynamic saveChatHistory(
  dynamic chatHistory,
  dynamic newChat,
) {
  // If chatHistory isn't a list, make it a list and then add newChat
  if (chatHistory is List) {
    chatHistory.add(newChat);
    return chatHistory;
  } else {
    return [newChat];
  }
}
```

Here's `convertToJSON()` function:

```
dynamic convertToJSON(String prompt) {
  // take the prompt and return a JSON with form [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
  return json.decode('{"role": "user", "content": "$prompt"}');
}
```

I've tried adding the `"system"` message in the `convertToJSON()` function like this:

```
dynamic convertToJSON(String prompt) {
  // take the prompt and return a JSON with form [{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
  return json.decode('[{"role": "system", "content": "system message"}, {"role": "user", "content": "$prompt"}]');
}
```

but this is returning a `400` error code that indicates `bad request`.

Comment: have you tried to send your request body hardcoded? You can simulate an array of conversation between user and system, and check if your HTTP request is structured correctly.

If it works, the body content formation has some bug. And I'm worried about your serializeJson function because the message prompt would never be a Map. It can only be a List. Even if the List has only one message.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing wrong when you try to serialize the prompt on your `_serializeJson` method.

Even if your chatPrompt has only one message, you need to define the message content as a List. I would try to set your body message hardcoded simulating a conversation between user and system to check if there's any error on your HTTP request.

If the request works with a hardcoded body, be sure that the problem is in your serialization methods.

Comment: Everything is working fine. It's just I am unable to figure out where to insert the "system" message manually.

Comment: Understood. I'll do another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenAI docs have many examples](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) about how to use their APIs. To your case on the `messages` parameter you will have a list of objects. These objects are the messages entities that compose the conversation.

You can add a initial message to the system that gives an orientation about how it should behave. For example:

```
   {
      "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      "messages": [
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."}, 
        {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"},
        ...
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your chat history is already a list, and even if it is not a list, saving it converts to List. So your convertToJSON function should be like the following.

```
dynamic convertToJSONForSystem(String prompt) {
  return json.decode('{"role": "system", "content": "$prompt"}');
}
```

Otherwise your body's messages property is like `"messages": "[[{role: system, content: system message}, {role: user, content: Hello}]]"` but this is wrong and we need like `"messages": "[{role: system, content: system message}, {role: user, content: Hello}]"`.